# If p value == String not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting to study javascript, with jQuery.

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p1").click(function(){

        var input = document.getElementById("p3");

        if (input.value == "Hi")
        {
            message = "Bye";
        } else {
            message = "Hi";
        }

        $("#p3").text(message);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

    <p id="p1">Click on me.</p>
    <p id="p2">Click on me again.</p>
    <p id="p3">Click on me one more time.</p>

</div>
```

It works in the first click in p1, but when I click again it doesn't change to "Bye"

Comment: I would recommend you to change `if (input.value == "Hi")` with `if (input.value === "Hi")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a `p`aragraph, not an `input`, so `.value` doesn't give what you need. Instead use `.textContent`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#p1").click(function() {

    var input = document.getElementById("p3");

    if (input.textContent == "Hi") {
      message = "Bye";
    } else {
      message = "Hi";
    }

    $("#p3").text(message);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

  <p id="p1">Click on me.</p>
  <p id="p2">Click on me again.</p>
  <p id="p3">Click on me one more time.</p>

</div>
```

---

Here's a no-jQuery version:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector("#p1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var p3 = document.getElementById("p3");
    p3.textContent = p3.textContent == "Hi" ? "Bye" : "Hi";
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p id="p1">Click on me.</p>
  <p id="p2">Click on me again.</p>
  <p id="p3">Click on me one more time.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For consistency sake, i'd looks the p3 up with jQuery and use the text() method off of it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $p3 = $('#p3');
    
    $("#p1").click(function(){
      var message = "Hi";
      
      if ($p3.text() === "Hi") message = "Bye";

      $p3.text(message);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

    <p id="p1">Click on me.</p>
    <p id="p2">Click on me again.</p>
    <p id="p3">Click on me one more time.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the `if (input.value == "Hi")` will always return false because input value is undefined hence always showing **"Hi"**